# Spring data mongodb Find by nested attribute in document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Im using Spring data mongodb, and I was wondering how can I make a find using a nested attribute documents, using Repositories.
Let´s imagine that I have this document:

```
{
    A:"val",
    B:{a:1, b:"test"},
    B:{a:1, b:"test"}
}
```

And what I would like is make a find like `findByAa(int a);`

But that does not works, somebody can help me please!

PS:I willing to not use mongoTemplate but repository.

Thanks

Comment: I think it helps if you provide some source code you already have

Comment: That´s the collection that I have and I just want to do a findByBa(int a) where B is the document and a is the attribute of the document where I want to search

Comment: I found a solution by myself using  @Query("{B.a:?0}")